# Notation without cases? $f(x)=\begin{cases}p,&\text{if $x=p^k$}\\1,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, functional-equations

Is there any other way to write the function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}p,&\text{if $x=p^k$}\\1,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
when $p$ is prime and $k\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: What is wrong with the way you have written it? It is admirably clear. But you could use the von Mangold function $\Lambda(n)$ which is $\ln p$ for $n=p^k$ and 0 otherwise. So your $f(x)=e^{\Lambda(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)$ is well-known in number theory. It is $\ln p$ for $n$ a power of a prime $p$ and 0 otherwise, so your $f(x)=e^{\Lambda(x)}$. However it is normally only defined on the positive integers. So it is not so good if you want your function defined on the reals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Besides my fuction only need to be defined for positiv integers ;)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle f(x) = p^{\min(v_p(x), 1)(1-\min(\sum_{l \ne p} v_l(x), 1))}$, not that the expression makes the function much easier to work with.